# Is there a specific command that changes all of the folders to a specific color?

Tags: command-line, directory, gui, colors

So I added the following commands to enable folder colors in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install folder-color
nautilus -q
```

and I was wondering if there is a specific command to change all of the folders to a specific color rather than having to do each folder individually like this .

[image: Changing the files by right clicking on the folder and right clicking again on the color]

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS version

Comment: If you had the default theme, then I would have suggested to change the entire icon set. But that interferes with every icon system-wide, not just those folders...

Comment: Anyways, just for the record, for the default theme, and if you don't mind that all icons get replaced system-wide, then `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`. This gives you an extra settings window. It has an "Appearance" tab, and within it, it offers an "Icons" field. There you can switch the icon-set system wide. I for one picked the "Humanity" set, which was used by default with the Unity desktops.

Comment: For the custom theme, maybe you could look into "forking" your currently used icon set: find where it resides on the system, create a copy of it, modify only the folder icon in it, and then point your theme to use this modified copy of the icon set...

Comment: Okay, I will look into that.